# error when i try to load the dashboard ( OpenHRMS odoo 13 CE)

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12, odoo-13

i'm facing a problem with OpenHRMS module for Odoo 13 CE , when i try to load the dashboard , i have this error

> list([d for d in month_join if d['l_month'] == month_emp[1].split('
> ')[:1][0].strip()[:3]])[0][ IndexError: list index out of range

Those two lines of code are the problem , but i didn't know what's the matter :

```
match_join = \
                list(filter(lambda d: d['l_month'] == month_emp[1].split(' ')[:1][0].strip()[:3], month_join))[0][
                    'count']
match_resign = \
                list(filter(lambda d: d['l_month'] == month_emp[1].split(' ')[:1][0].strip()[:3], month_resign))[0][
                    'count']
```

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it for me:

```
@api.model
    def get_attrition_rate(self):
        month_attrition = []
        monthly_join_resign = self.join_resign_trends()
        month_join = monthly_join_resign[0]['values']
        month_resign = monthly_join_resign[1]['values']
        sql = """
        SELECT (date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE))::date - interval '1' month * s.a AS month_start
        FROM generate_series(0,11,1) AS s(a);"""
        self._cr.execute(sql)
        month_start_list = self._cr.fetchall()
        for month_date in month_start_list:
            self._cr.execute("""select count(id), to_char(date '%s', 'Month YYYY') as l_month from hr_employee
            where resign_date > date '%s' or resign_date is null and joining_date < date '%s'
            """ % (month_date[0], month_date[0], month_date[0],))
            month_emp = self._cr.fetchone()
            # month_emp = (month_emp[0], month_emp[1].split(' ')[:1][0].strip()[:3])
            month_join_filter = filter(lambda d: d['l_month'] == month_emp[1].split(' ')[:1][0].strip()[:3], month_join)
            match_join = 0
            if len(tuple(month_join_filter)) > 0:
                match_join = list(month_join_filter)[0]['count']
            month_resign_filter = filter(lambda d: d['l_month'] == month_emp[1].split(' ')[:1][0].strip()[:3], month_resign)
            match_resign = 0
            if len(tuple(month_resign_filter)) > 0:
                match_resign = list(month_resign_filter)[0]['count']
            month_avg = (month_emp[0] + match_join - match_resign + month_emp[0]) / 2
            attrition_rate = (match_resign / month_avg) * 100 if month_avg != 0 else 0

            vals = {
                # 'month': month_emp[1].split(' ')[:1][0].strip()[:3] + ' ' + month_emp[1].split(' ')[-1:][0],
                'month': month_emp[1].split(' ')[:1][0].strip()[:3],
                'attrition_rate': round(float(attrition_rate), 2)
            }
            month_attrition.append(vals)
            return month_attrition
```